# Error appears when building app that uses VTK in release mode

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, vtk

Good day everyone!

We're developing an app under Windows 7 (64 bit) using the `Qt 4.8` framework and `VTK`. We're coding in `C++` using `QtCreator` and the `MingW-32` compiler.
In debug mode the compilation ends ok and we can launch and test the app. However, now that we want to build a release version, wild error messages appeared:

```
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

My partner has googled a bit and found that this is a rather common issue when trying to build a release version using VTK. The solution proposed is to add the path to the VTK debug library into the system path, before the release one. However, that didn't work for us. As of now, we're cluelessly trying to get the building done.

Do you have any idea what the solution might be?.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

**EDIT:** Here's the link with the supposed solution to this problem: [supposed solution](http://dzenanz.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/qwidget-must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qpaintdevice/)

Comment: This error melts away if you use CMake to build. I would recommend using it as these sorts of nuisance compile errors are much better dealt with using Kitware's build mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try building the project with CMake, but I'm also interested in if there's another way of resolving this problem.